# bash- Remove a string using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have want to delete only the string `" - [$the_real_ip]"` and one space next to that using `sed` from the following log stream format:

> `log-format-upstream: '$remote_addr - [$proxy_protocol_addr] - [$the_real_ip] - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"`

This is what I tried that doesn't work for me:

1. input_file has the above content.
2. remove the `- [$the_real_ip]`
3. Ran below command.

`sed 's/- [$the_real_ip]//g'  input_file > output_file`

I am able to remove the `[$the_real_ip]` using the command:

`sed 's/\[$the_real_ip]*\]//g'`  input_file

I also wanted to a remove the `-` next to `$the_real_ip]` and an extra space created after deleting. How can I do that?

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to  their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: please let me  know if it requires more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the special regex chars:

```
sed 's/ - \[$the_real_ip\]//g' input_file
```

Output:

```
log-format-upstream: '$remote_addr - [$proxy_protocol_addr] - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"
```

Comment: That quotes the `$` so the variable doesn't expand. Try double quotes, or to avoid the *extra* backslash mess, switching quotes around the var.

Comment: @PaulHodges, SFAICT, the OP doesn't wish to expand the variable.

Comment: or is maybe using it representatively of the actual value, not really as a variable at all. You may be entirely correct; I just didn't want to assume one way or the other. OP's use of single quotes is either intentional (and so you're right), or part of the problem.